# Mapping a SubClass in Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've been trying to perform a login process in my new web app, It used to be working but since I made the User model composed of UserData and Profile subclasses, the Tomcat is showing me a UserData not mapped :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserData is not mapped [from UserData u where u.username = :Username]
```

Userlogin DAO :

```
public UserData getUsername(String username) {
    List<UserData> userList = new ArrayList<UserData>();
    Query query = openSession().createQuery("from UserData u where u.username = :Username");
    query.setParameter("Username", username);
    userList = query.list();
    if (userList.size() > 0)
        return userList.get(0);
    else
        return null;
}
```

Model :

```
public class Usermanager {


    @Entity
    @Table(name="USER") 
    public class UserData implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        int iduser;
        String username;
        String password;
        int idprofile;
        int accountstatus;

        public int getIduser() {
            return iduser;
        }
        public void setIduser(int iduser) {
            this.iduser = iduser;
        }
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
        public int getIdprofile() {
            return idprofile;
        }
        public void setIdprofile(int idprofile) {
            this.idprofile = idprofile;
        }
        public int getAccountstatus() {
            return accountstatus;
        }
        public void setAccountstatus(int accountstatus) {
            this.accountstatus = accountstatus;
        }

    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name="PROFILE")
    public class Profile implements Serializable { ... }
}
```

Full StackTrace :

```
    sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:empsuite' did not find a matching property.
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server built:          Feb 15 2015 18:10:42 UTC
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server number:         8.0.20.0
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Name:               Windows 10
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Version:            10.0
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Architecture:          amd64
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Version:           1.8.0_60-b27
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\ceo\Desktop\BluePen Labs\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.20
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\ceo\Desktop\BluePen Labs\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.20
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\ceo\Desktop\BluePen Labs\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.20\endorsed
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Maven\bin;C:\eclipse;;.
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFOS: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFOS: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 4009 ms
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Démarrage du service Catalina
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:11 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:12 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFOS: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [179] milliseconds.
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:25 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFOS: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:26 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFOS: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Sep 07 18:53:26 WAT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:26 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:27 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-context.xml]
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:28 PM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion performVersionChecks
INFOS: You are running with Spring Security Core 3.2.0.RELEASE
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:28 PM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
INFOS: Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.2.0.RELEASE
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:29 PM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFOS: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:29 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFOS: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:31 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:31 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:31 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:31 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:32 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFOS: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hge1369b1aviaj8nw80g0|405f41fb, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge1369b1aviaj8nw80g0|405f41fb, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost/empsdb, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 2, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 1, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:33 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:33 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:33 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:33 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:34 PM org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator <init>
INFO: HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: empsuite.model.Usermanager$UserData (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:34 PM org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator <init>
INFO: HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: empsuite.model.Usermanager$Profile (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:35 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFOS: Using DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hge1369b1aviaj8nw80g0|405f41fb, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge1369b1aviaj8nw80g0|405f41fb, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost/empsdb, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 2, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 1, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:35 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFOS: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 10320 ms
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:35 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFOS: Initialisation de Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) pour le contexte «/empsuite»
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:36 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFOS: JSF1048 : Présence d’annotations PostConstruct/PreDestroy  Les méthodes de beans gérés marquées avec ces annotations auront des annotations dites traitées.
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:39 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFOS: Monitoring file:/C:/Users/ceo/Desktop/BluePen%20Labs/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/empsuite/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:39 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFOS: Running on PrimeFaces 4.0
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 29484 ms
sept. 07, 2015 6:53:44 PM com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap put
AVERTISSEMENT: JSF1063 : AVERTISSEMENT ! Définition d’une valeur d’attribut non-sérialisable dans HttpSession (clé : UserloginMB, classe de la valeur : empsuite.managedbean.UserloginManagedBean).
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: UserData is not mapped [from UserData u where u.username = :Username]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at empsuite.managedbean.UserloginManagedBean.login(UserloginManagedBean.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener.processAction(FlowActionListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.faces.model.SelectionTrackingActionListener.processAction(SelectionTrackingActionListener.java:64)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserData is not mapped [from UserData u where u.username = :Username]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3252)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3141)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:694)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:550)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1537)
    at empsuite.dao.UserloginDAOImpl.getUsername(UserloginDAOImpl.java:24)
    at empsuite.service.UserloginService.loadUserByUsername(UserloginService.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:101)
    ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What you have done there are not subclasses, but inner classes.* I am not fully sure on what relation do you plan to build between your own classes, but the **UserManager.java file should not contain the definitions of your entities.**

- If you want to Extend UserManager (does not seem like a good solution, but still): you need a UserManager.java, and two other .java files for your entities, both marked as "extends Usermanager" and with @Entity annotation.
- If you want your UserManager class to contain these elements, just simply decleare two variables with these types and create the two other java classes with @Entity annotation.